# How I get the field from a query using a foreach in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

```
$codGo = DB::table('tb_go')
           ->select('cod_go', 'data', 'item_contab', 'equi_func1_mat', 
                    'equi_func2_mat', 'equi_func3_mat', 'equi_func4_mat')
           ->get();

foreach($codGo as $go)
{
   $item = $codGo->item_contab;
}
```

How can I do something like this?

I get this error:
Trying to get property of non-object

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use `$go` not `$codGo`.

Comment: thx man, I'm a noob in laravel yet hahaha +rep